# Line Break using Clipboard SetText

Tags: c#

How can I add line breaks using the SetText method?

I tried `Clipboard.SetText("eee \n xxxx");` but it doesn't give me the expected result when I paste the clipboard data in the notepad.

Expected result:

```
eee
xxxx
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: something: eee(square character)xxxx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Windows uses CR+LF pairs to indicate a new line. This equates to `"\r\n"` in C#. However, you are just sending `"\n"`, i.e. a single LF rather than a CR+LF pair.

Use [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx) rather than of `"\n"`. This is the  idomatic way to spell `"\r\n"` in C#. As a bonus, if you ever ran your code on a *nix platform, `Environment.NewLine` would evaluate to "\n" which is the *nix new line indicator. Finally, in my view `Environment.NewLine` is preferable from a readability perspective. It documents what this thing is logically rather than relying on you knowing the magic constants.

Comment: Hi David, where can I find a reference for this kind of shorthands or alike?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a single list of useful knowledge like this. You just pick this stuff up as you go along. Higher level languages do a good job of shielding you from all this detail but every now and again you run into it.

Comment: hey  @DavidHeffernan , thanks but I have tried to use this  just end of string but it didn't work---> Clipboard.SetText("eeexxxx" + Environment.NewLine);

Comment: actually  I want append a Enter Character to end of my string, but it hasn't work

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
Clipboard.SetText("eee" + Environment.NewLine + "xxxx");
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this works good as well:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Clipboard.SetText(this.txtCopyJS.Text.Replace("\n", "\r\n"));
```

Comment: This is particularly handy when dealing with C++ strings.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a bit late... but I often use [StringBuilder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx) for memory and performance reasons and it' has a very handy [AppendLine()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline(v=vs.110).aspx) method.