# Creating a copy to clipboard button with line breaks in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I am new to C# coding and am having a difficult time trying to navigate it when attempting to find resources online.

I am attempting to make a simple program that has buttons that I can click and it will copy to a string of text to the clipboard with line breaks.

Example:

First Line

Second Line

Third Line

I have been able to create the button and copy it to the clipboard successfully, but I can't seem to figure out how to add line breaks.

I tried referring to this post [Line Break using Clipboard SetText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033191/line-break-using-clipboard-settext)    but it doesn't seem to work for me.

Here is my code currently:

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void RepairInstall(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Clipboard.SetText("First Line" + 
            "  Second Line");
    }
    }
    }
```

How would I set it up so that I can insert line breaks into the clipboard?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a line break between the lines:

```
"Line 1\nLine 2"
```

Or

```
"Line 1" + Environment.NewLine + "Line 2"
```

You can also use verbatim string to achieve that, a verbatim string (that is prefixed with the `@` character), may have line breaks.

```
@"Line 1
Line 2"
```

Why your code doesn't work:
C#, ignores line breaks in its code. The code outside the string (surrounding the plus sign in your code), are ignored, and they are all treated like a single space. You have to make sure the line break is part of the string by including it in the string itself.

See more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090).

Comment: Or `Environment.NewLine`

Comment: I'm on mobile, too long for typing...

Comment: Thanks a lot! I used the verbatim string method you mentioned and it works!

Comment: Great. If my post helped you, consider marking it as answer by selecting the V in the left side of it.